# Yii2 many to many

Tags: activerecord, php, yii

Здравствуйте, у меня есть интернет магазин на Yii, в нем имеется фильтр товаров по производителям а именно в страничке выбранной категории, реляция следующая:

```
'brands' => [
   self::MANY_MANY, 
   'Brands', 
   'products(category_id, brands_id)', 
   'condition'=>'brands.checked=1'
 ],
```

Таким образом я получаю список только тех производителей чьи товары есть в данной категории, как реализовать это на Yii2, где нет many-to-many?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде как то так:

```
public function getBrands()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Brands::className(), [
        'category_id' => 'brands_id'
    ])->where(['checked' => 1])
    ->via('products');
}
```

Подробности: http://stuff.cebe.cc/yii2docs/guide-db-active-record.html#relations-with-pivot-table

Comment: Спасибо, только category_id нужно сменить на id, и заработало все как надо.